# Wkhtmltopdf patched QT issue with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, wkhtmltopdf

I get this JavaScript error when running any version of wkhtmltopdf with patched Qt:

```
Warning: undefined:0 Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ng due to:
'undefined' is not an object
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerrp0=ng&p1='undefined'%20is%20not%20an%20object
```

(I'm trying to render a page with angularjs 1.5).

When I use a version of wkhtmltopdf without patched Qt I don't get the error and everything works fine.

I use [this heroku buildpack](https://github.com/dscout/wkhtmltopdf-buildpack) which installs version 0.12.3 with patched Qt, and I got this error.

Any idea how to solve my problem? I may install wkhtmltopdf without patched Qt on production but it seems I will have to compile it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work with all versions: I needed a special version of the .bind() JavaScript function polyfill:

```
var isFunction = function (o) {
return typeof o == 'function';
};

var bind,
slice = [].slice,
proto = Function.prototype,
featureMap;

featureMap = {
'function-bind': 'bind'
};

function has(feature) {
  var prop = featureMap[feature];
  return isFunction(proto[prop]);
}

// check for missing features
if (!has('function-bind')) {
  // adapted from Mozilla Developer Network example at
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind
  bind = function bind(obj) {
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 1),
      self = this,
      nop = function() {
      },
      bound = function() {
        return self.apply(this instanceof nop ? this : (obj || {}), args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
      };
    nop.prototype = this.prototype || {}; // Firefox cries sometimes if prototype is undefined
    bound.prototype = new nop();
    return bound;
  };
  proto.bind = bind;
}
```

Comment: I am also facing same isue, where should i put this?

Comment: did you put the polyfill I posted in your HTML?

Comment: Where do i need to add this code? I copy this on aspx page script tag but still ng-model bindings not working

Comment: getting the same error. I'm using Angel Bootstrap Theme for AngularJS. What Change should I do?

Comment: put it in your main/root html file (index.html)